# Is it possible to control multiple VideoWidgets with one MediaPlayer?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

I wonder if it is possible to play a video using the Qt5 QtMultimedia library in 3 widgets simultaneously.

I have a video that I would like to show in 3 widgets: one showing the full video, another focusing on some object moving in the video, and a last one again focused in some other object.

I've been struggling for a bit now and I'm starting to doubt if my effort will be worthy...

Has anyone tried something similar and/or could give me some tips on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to show a vídeo in multiple widgets is using a custom Video Surface class, and use them to generate a serie of `QImage` for you, and process/show those images the way you like.

Example of a custom Video Surface:

```
/* Here is our custom video surface, */
class VideoSurface : public QAbstractVideoSurface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    VideoSurface(QObject *parent = 0) : QAbstractVideoSurface(parent)
    {
    }

    QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>
    supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType) const
    {
        return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>() << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32;
    }

    /* this will get the QVideoFrame and convert to QImage. */
    bool present(const QVideoFrame& frame)
    {
        if (frame.isValid())
        {
            QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
            cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
            const QImage img = QImage(cloneFrame.bits(),
                                      cloneFrame.width(),
                                      cloneFrame.height(),
                                      QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()));

            cloneFrame.unmap();

            emit readyRead(img);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

signals:
    void readyRead(QImage);
};
```

Here you have a sample Project:

[Double View project](https://mega.co.nz/#!Al4GiCQR!7zBsuZRL8lVqVJ6CnKX3-duYUY0dSKXW0Y-gOi72yeM)

Screenshot:

[image: Double View]

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a huge help! For now, on some test videos I got some missing GStreamer plug-in error. I intend to grab and work the frames with OpenCV, do you think this will be a problem?

Comment: About your "missing GStreamer" this may happen because QMediaPlayer not support all videos formats, but i'm not sure because I tried it with one video :), and I don't believe that uses the grab with OpenCV will be a problem, you'll only need to convert the QImage to the respective OpenCV image as on the following example: [OpenCV and QImage](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/)

Comment: @AntonioDias The link is dead. I wish you also posted the code for how the class is used. Do I need to call the `start()` function? Why does my media player open windows for playing instead of the widget?